# Minecraft and FTB crashing on windows 8.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-8.1

So... I have reacently installed windows 8.1 on my pc. Now i dual boot it with windows 7 and Ubuntu.On windows 7 i play minecraft and FTB with no problems. But, on windows 8.1 minecraft and FTB crashes before it even shows the Mojang logo it just crashes. The first line in the crash report is this: "org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated"
I have updated java to 64bit.
Also if i enter device manager in windows 8.1 after my graphics card it says microsoft Corp. Could that me the problem ?

PC:
CPU: AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core processor  6000+ @3.01 GHz 
RAM: 5 GB DDR2 
Graphics: ATI Readon HD 2600 PRO Memory: 2559 MB total aviable graphics memory 
Windows 7 Profesional  and Windows 8.1 as OSs

If anything else is required for anyone, comment below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the crash log? It is located at C:/Users/<your user>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/crash-reports. Upload to pastebin and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was i was running Microsoft provided version of my graphics drivers! Witch means that when i installed windows 8 Microsoft providied my system with the graphics drivers and the drivers were not "full" version. You can check that by right clicking on your start icon in the lower left corner (while in desktop view) and select device manager and under display drives it will say your graphics card name and "(Microsoft Corporation)" so in that case uninstall the graphics drivers and install the drivers that you will find on your graphics card's manufacturer's website!
And thats how i fixed my problem! Sry for taking too long for posting a answer but now i know that i will be able to help people with the same problem find the solution!